# Enhance Server Security

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-18.04, php7

I don't know if this is the right place for my question.

I'm creating a web server with Apache and PHP, but I want to make it as secure as possible.

A set of software to keep the server secure, is it recommended to use OSSEC, mod_evasive, and mod_security with the OWASP rule set?

Or is it not necessary to use OSSEC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you some recommendation.

*Enhanse your server security
    You could use CIS Benchmark for you Operative System

- Enhanse you Web Server Security
- Be carefull with your firewall configuration
- Install some security components like an AntiDDos, IDS, IPS, in your Firewall( If you
- Update you OS and all component involved.
- Run an vulnerability scanning, port scanning in order to check unneccesary port open, or vulnerability associated with your WS or OS.

if you don't have a firewall and don't have money to buy one, I will recommend you a good opensource firewall like  pfsense).

Comment: Hi @MarcosVera. Thank you very much for the recommendations. The CIS Benchmark contains excellent content that I will follow.

Do you have any suggestions for AntiDDoS, IDS and IPS software?

Comment: IDS/IPS you could use snort is very good. For AntiDDOS you could try with Fail2Ban.